"Insmod cryptodisk" is missing from grub.cfg?
I am following this guide this guide on /boot encryption for my Ubuntu system. I am currently on section 3, after deciding to not complete section 4. (i.e, I don't wish to avoid multiple password prompts). The guide has the commands run on the native OS, but I have had some issues due to that so I'm running them on a live OS and using chroot when necessary. The native OS is mounted to /mnt.
After editing /mnt/etc/default/grub, running chroot /mnt update-grub and chroot /mnt grub-install /dev/sda finishes without errors, but insmod cryptodisk doesn't appear in grub.cfg when it should. It should appear several times throughout the file, but instead it only appears once near the top, because of the GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES option. I have done "test runs" on this same system before (it is a VM so cloning is easy) and insmod cryptodisk was added in the test runs. So why is it not being added to the grub.cfg now? My pre-question  research found this forum, but I've has no success either before or after enabling the GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES option detailed there.

Thank you so much for all the help!
Edit 1: I've tried the advice found in this post, with no success. Using --rbind instead of --bind was used in a previous test run as well and was the reason that test run succeeded, but it is not helping now. Mounting efivarfs also does not help. Specifying chroot /mnt grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi does not help either. They cause grub-install to finish without errors, but the sections in grub.cfg about cryptodisk are still missing.
